# Discord Bot Cant Read Messages

Tags: discord.py, bots

(im new to discord bots)
whenever i type a message the message.content is empty and im assuming its because I didnt turn on message.read, but whenever I tick the box it asks me for a redirect url & uri but it wont let me type/select anything so i hane no clue what to do.
My friend has made a bot which can read text but he never had this error.
I've tried to look this up like 10 times but noone else seems to have had this problem.
[Select Redirect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0jpH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong tab. Make sure you're in `Bot` in the left-hand side of the developer panel.

The discord.py docs have a pretty clear guide on how to enable intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

You're looking for the `message_content` intent here. Make sure to enable it in your code as well.